# iOS Enterprise Program vs. iOS Developer Program

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution, enterprise, udid

I am facing some issues related with iOS Developer program and iOS Enterprise Program. One of my client ask me to suggest one of them. Please answer my questions related to iOS Enterprise Program-

1. If i purchase an iOS Enterprise account so when it is available for in-house application distribution?
2. How many device i have on which i can install my app?
3. Do i need UDID of all devices?
4. What if i want to add some new devices?
5. If it is same Ad-hoc distribution the what is the expiry date of Ad-hoc certificate?

Thanks

Comment: Now the enterprise account is not good to apply, many people do not have this kind of account, you can look at this website,https://www.iosenterpriseaccount.com/, 
the enterprise program in principle can let a lot of people(no limit) inside the company to use, while the iOS developer program can be published to the public.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. As soon as you sign the contracts and make the purchase and Apple verifies all the information, you can create your distribution certificate, provisioning profile and then sign your app with the certificate, and distribute your app with the profile.
2. There is no limit to the number of devices.
3. No, you do not need to get the UDID's of the devices for Enterprise distribution.
4. Just send the app and the distribution provisioning profile to the user who has the new device.
5. The certificate is used to sign the app - to my knowledge there is not an "ad-hoc" vs. "distribution" certificate.

Comment: based on #4, what's the difference between ad-hoc distribution and enterprise then? Do I have to send .app and provision profile to individual users? Can't that be done from Apple itself?

Comment: Ad-hoc and enterprise are based on two different development licenses, which allow you to create two different kinds of certificates.  Ad-hoc is for testing apps that will eventually be distributed via the app store; enterprise is for apps that will be distributed within an enterprise (no Apple app store involved).

Answer (score 3):

Hy Rayfleck,
I'm not sure about that..
Reading this post: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Has-anyone-had-experience-iOS-72283.S.52864455 
made me realize that:

Enterprise license can do 2 different kind of release:

- release for internal distribution
- release for a third party distribution

The internal distribution has no limit of devices

The third party distribution is limited to only 100 devices..

Comment: Do you know if the third party distribution (Ad Hoc distribution) requires the UDIDs?

Comment: @powtac - yes it does require the UDID's.

Comment: could I potentially require UDIDs for internal distribution as well?