# Deploy my App for Testing without Using UDID

Tags: ios, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

I am an new Apple Developer, I am using the Apple Enterprise Program.
I looking for a way to send my App for testing some iPhone/iPad, the problem they are not in the Provisioning Profile.

I know there is a way, I had a Company they sent me on the same way so I can download the app from they server on my iPads without to sending my UDID.
How is this Possible? 
Can you help me?

I don't know how its work.

I created a Ad Hoc Certificate,
I created a App ID
I created a Ad Hoc Provisions Profile.

but I can only Install the App on iPads/iPhones where in my Device List.

Can you help me? 
like a Tutorial or tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Do you have an Enterprise account or the normal developer account?

Comment: You can use the "In-house" distribution profile in your Enterprise developer account. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830194/can-i-distribute-my-app-for-any-device-without-udid

Comment: this Question is not the same ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the InHouse profile create with your enterprise account. AdHoc need an UDID so you can not use this.

But be aware that some strict rules about using the InHouse profiles, you need to make sure that the download is protected so that not everyone can just download it.

Comment: PERFECT THANK YOUUUU the other posts are not so clear but perfekt thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for TestFlight,  [Have a look](http://www.testflightapp.com)

Archive your app, Select option "Submit for Enterprise or Ad hoc Deployment", Select your distribution profile from the list and upload it to testflight, Your client can download and install it directly from there.Its quite easy and simple

Hope this helps :)

Comment: TestFlight is only an webbased deployment system, you still need to sign your apps with a profile. The question is how to distributed an app without an UDID and this is not something TestFlight can solve.