# Testing IOS app on multiple machine without UDID

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm currently developing a game for the IOS, I have managed to deployed the game to an iPad for testing which is great (using xCode). However, I'm wondering if there's a way to install an app into an IOS device without having to register its UDID? For example if I want to install a version of the game on a publisher device, can I just create some sort of package and email it to them and they can install on their own?

I tried checking around and the closest thing seems to be the Ad Hoc Provisioning? But unless I'm mistaken, Ad Hoc still requires me to register the UDID of the device. I tried checking 
 [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH12-SW2), 
but can't really understand it. The images also seems to be different then what I'm seeing in xCode which kinda makes me lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830194/can-i-distribute-my-app-for-any-device-without-udid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to archive your app using the Enterprise deployment target.

How it works :

1. Generate the ipa for **entreprise distribution** (with the correct provisioning profiles) ; the other distribution system requires the UDID of every device to be added to your developer profile.
2. Upload the ipa wherever you want, if you need something beautiful, you could make an app that lists your IPA (your store ^^) with information about it, and a link to download it (look below)
3. Upload the .plist file and make it so the url in the url field is the .ipa that you uploaded on step 1.
4. Create a basic HTML page with this line where you want it :

   ```
   *<*a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=YOUR-UPLOADED-PLIST-FILE.plist">Clic here ;-)</a>
   ```

Users can now clic it and download ;)

(I had to add two ** at the start otherwise SO would show it as a link.)

I'm not sure if you can publish your store app on the app store though, and I think you only need the 99$/y subscription. This needs to be checked.

Do you need more information?

Comment: Enterprise program costs $299/year. Is there any alternative way of generating an ipa for entreprise distribution?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the UDID, the only way to test on real device (without jailbreaking of course) is to use TestFlight solution provided by Apple.
But this means you restrict to iOS 8 devices, and you need to add the iTunes account in your developer portal, and add it to the "Internal Tester".

You might be interested with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the in-house provisioning but you will need that you subscribe as iOS Developer Enterprise Program. 
There is more details on this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-in-house-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a third platform such as [Testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com) or [Crahlytics](https://crashlytics.com) to manage providing app builds to your testers.
You have only to invite your testers to join a team of testers and the platform takes in charge getting your testers' UDIDs for you.
Afterward you should add these UDIDs to your provisioning profile for an ad-hoc distribution in the  [Apple's members center](http://developer.apple.com).

Comment: Testflight is no longer 3rd party.  Apple gobbled them up.