# How to distribute ios app without UUID

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I am exporting file using AdHoc and generate a link after uploading ipa file on [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/).

When i install my app On my iphone, it is not installing. i am getting error

Unable to install, cancel or retry.

Any suggestions for the same

Thanks

Comment: While you are distributing the app are you using the adhoc provisioning profiles ?

Comment: Yes, i am using adhoc provision profile

Comment: have u set valid provisioning profile and code signing identity?

Comment: @HardikShekhat: I am able to install on one device but not to other devices without uuid. code signing was automatic

Comment: @HituBansal ok then As per my knowledge I think you can't do that thing with Diawi.  plz try below answer and if it worked then plz also tell me. I also generally distribute app with Diawi.

Answer (score 5):

1: code signing the IPA is required

#### for installing it you have 3 options to sign it

a. adhoc with UUIDs (the device identifier has to be registered)

b. 'enterprise-inhouse' (requires no registration of UUIDs!)

*c. developer certificates (only devs in your home team can install those apps)

---

--> if you can, buy b (check if the license is appropriate)

Comment: Will option c will help without UUID.

Comment: yes, but only for ppl in the team. no non-dev device will be able to use the app.

Comment: is there is any other option to do the same without using the enterprise-inhouse. as we have developer account only and our requirement is to give app outside from apple store

Answer (score 2):

You are very likely only having a "Developer" license with Apple, the $99 a year plan. In order for you to install ipa files onto a device, you have to register the device's UUID in your Apple Account.  You can view your device UUID by connecting the device to iTune.

Enterprise license, the $299 plan does not require knowledge of device UUID.

More information is available at [Can I distribute my App for any device without UDID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830194/can-i-distribute-my-app-for-any-device-without-udid)

Answer (score 1):

I have already faced this problem for that I have sent the app through AppStore, the user can install it via testflightapp for the first time after that we can use diawi.com to distribute

Comment: User is not going to install test flight in my case.

Answer (score 0):

When you export AdHoc build, you need to make sure that code signing identities have the device UDID on which you are trying to install. If you want to install .ipa without UDID, set code signing to none. But I am not sure exporting this way would allow you to install.