# Can I install .ipa in any iphone device without UDID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes, ipa

I have an objective c application, I want save an .ipa and send this file to any person. I'm trying to generate this from xcode->product->archive

I'm trying install this to device dragging and dropping the .ipa to iTunes, but this not work. Show installing, the icon is showed a second on the iphone, but this is deleted automatically...
But I haven't udid of other devices.

It's possible? How can I do this?

Comment: you can also sign your `.ipa` file with a proper distribution certificate which does not require a single UDID, and you can install it via iTunes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I distribute my App for any device without UDID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830194/can-i-distribute-my-app-for-any-device-without-udid)

Answer (score 0):

Import ipa to your itunes. Connect your iphone to iTunes then install application just by click on install and then sync.

or

Upload your ipa file to diawi server (it is free) where if you open the link through your browser , then it automatically asks you for an install option.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach for you, May be it will help for you:

1. You have update your provisioning profile with containing all UDIDs you want.
2. If you want to go with another way, You can install your ipa in this way: Click on window menu of Xcode-> Devices, you will see your connected device and see no of apps installed in your device. Drag your ipa in that area.

Comment: But for this I need add the device, I want send the ipa and they go to install automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com) account, you will create app from [Itunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and App TestFlight add Internal Testing user. You just need email address which device use AppStore.