# IOS Enterprise Program related query

Tags: ios

Has anyone had experience with the iOS Developer Enterprise program? Is the distribution done via regular ad-hoc means (i.e. UDIDs must be registered)? Is there a max # of devices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Enterprise Program vs. iOS Developer Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306441/ios-enterprise-program-vs-ios-developer-program)

Comment: Have you read this question - it appears to have answers to your questions:http://stackoverflow.com/q/7306441/558933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise license allows both Ad-Hoc and In-House Distribution methods. The Enterprise license is mainly intended for companies and organizations that are creating proprietary iOS apps for internal distribution (In-house). you see 100 devices limit for Ad-Hoc and this is the limitation of this particular type of distributing apps. If you choose In-House Distribution, you will not be limited to the number of devices and you will only be limited to distribute your app only to the devices used by employees of your company.
With Enterprise Program participation you can only distribute the app inside your company/organization. UDIDs are not required, no max number of devices. You are not allowed to distribute the app outside of your company.
        The main benefit is that you can deploy private apps to iOS devices without needing to register UDIDs in the provisioning portal as you do when distributing Ad-hoc builds. On the other hand you're not allowed to distribute apps on the App Store.
        Only companies and organizations with a Dun & Bradstreet (D-U-N-S) Number can enroll to the Enterprise developer program.